# Need to know if a exe file contains at least an icon

Tags: delphi, icons, 64-bit, delphi-2009

I need to know if a exe file contains at least one icon. A fast way, if that's possible.
I tried with `PrivateExtractIcons` and it works, but only for 32 bit exe files.
It's not working for 64 bit exe files.
I need this to work with any exe file in any Windows >= XP (x86 and x64).

I'm using Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Call [`LoadLibraryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179) passing `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`.
2. Call [`EnumResourceTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648039%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to check if the module has any icon resources.

Note that this is not exhaustive since some applications (e.g. modern Office) store their image assets in custom form and not icon resources.

Comment: It is exhaustive, `RT_ICON` and `RT_GROUP_ICON` with `EnumResourceNames` is enough. Or simply `ExtractIcon(..., -1) > 0`

Comment: That's bold point. How would you know if two randomly selected bitmap resources do not comprise an icon?

Comment: @DavidB, there is no need for loop enumerating all of resource types. Types are known in advance.

Comment: *sigh* Suppose, we detected what file contains 42 of those "icons-but-not-much". Which status should we report to caller? `False`? `True`? `0.9 * True`?